# Entity frame to query multiple data sources

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, mongodb, multiple-databases

Is there a way that i can use entity framework to query across multiple data sources as in (mongodb, sql server, oracle) simultaneously. Like for example user accounts and profiles are on a sql server and other data on mongodb for quick access and some other data on oracle. Does  EF support querying multiple datasources this way? or is there any other solution that might support such features. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some clarification concerning what kinds of data you're trying to aggregate here, and why is it stored in different places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, EntityFramework can't do that. In fact, it cannot even do queries over two different contexts from one database.

You can write your own abstracting layer above EF which will forward your queries appropriately.

**Update:** as an afterthought - I don't think that writing one-DAL-to-rule-them-all is a good idea. Different datasources usually means different concerns, and that means you should separate them as different services. It's not so convenient at the first glance, but it (usually) pays in the long run.

Comment: Hmmm that means writing up a DAL that manages the queries among all the data sources and fills up custom models against them. Any other solution that might be doing this ? any ideas

Comment: I will add some thoughts to post.

Comment: so in other words changing the architecture in such way that all the data sources can exposed through separate WCF services providing there own data and then summing up the data on manager which consume all the services. Does this sound like a good approach ?

Comment: You don't have to think "WCF services". I am talking about plain and simple application services, which can be just interfaces. And no, it doesn't sound good to me to sum up all the data in data manager, because, as I've already said, most likely it is *unrelated* data.

Answer (score 0):

Their is no direct way with Entity Framework. But you can create EDMX and then can link different servers means this way you will have multiple DataSources

The EDMX item I am suggesting is called ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Comment: thanks got the idea but how do enterprise solutions developed in dotnet work. By writing custom DAL and managing through application to do all the job ?

Comment: @Wajeeh yes that is a good way, separate is out in to the DAL layer

Comment: i am trying to query different data sources can we link them togather. The data sources are for example mongoDb and sql server ?